# Create 'search' trigger before insert

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have the following sql syntax:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
BEFORE INSERT
   ON table FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

END;
```

I need to check the table for values where **field1='x'** and **field2='y'**. If the values are found want the insertion to **fail via php side**. `($mysqli->error)`

Comment: Are you saying you want the insert to fail if done via PHP, but not if it's done some other way?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by attempting to select that value using mysql and count the results (num_rows). If the result returns 0, then you insert data into mysql table, as there is no data with the same value in your table.

Comment: I'd like something more performance friendly, like the trigger